# Axios Doesn't Send Headers, Even The CORS Preflight Already Enabled

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cors, axios

Nodejss Server.js :

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
    res.header("Access-Control-Request-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, x-access-token");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, x-access-token");
    res.header("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, x-access-token");
    next();
});
```

Reactjs upload :

```
let axiosConfig = {
    headers: {
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        'crossDomain': true,
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
        'x-access-token': Cookies.get('token')
    }
};
axios.post('/api/file/upload',formData, axiosConfig).then(
    response => {
        console.log(response);
    }
).catch(
    function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
```

With postman, the post method works, when I try console.log(req.headers['x-access-token']); it returns the jwt token.

But with the browser, the post method works but the headers don't send, when I try console.log(req.headers['x-access-token']); it returns undefined. So its always give 403 status response.

Comment: The cookies are from different origin so you can't access them from current window with javascript. If you set `withCredentials` in request the browser would get/set the cross domain cookies and you could read the token cookie server side

Comment: About `withCredentials` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/withCredentials